# Use dplyr and do to build and use models

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using dplyr to build up a table of models

```
library(dplyr)

t1 <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do(model = lm(formula = Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data = .))
```

I know how to feed those models into subsequent functions, for example:

```
t2 <- t1 %>%
  do(summ = .$model %>% summary)
```

I'm hoping to join the two outputs into one table without losing the dplyr 'format'

Both of these solutions expand the lists out to text, which I do not want:

```
t3i <- merge(t1, t2)
t3ii  <- cbind(t1, t2)
```

This is an example of the result I want:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do(
    model = lm(formula = Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data = .),
    summ = .$model %>% summary
     )
```

But I need to produce t1 and t2 separately and then combine them - not do it all in one step.

Would an inner_join work and if so, how do I pull the Species column through in the 't2' step?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean in the last paragraph where you say "This is the result I want, but it cannot be done in the same 'do' call" - at least the code runs without errors and it's the same `do` call. So what exactly do you mean doesn't work?

Comment: The last example is the result I want, but it has to be achieved by joining 't1' and 't2'

Comment: The last iris pipe chain example above works like a charm and results in a data frame which stores the linear model and the summary objects in two separate columns. Isn't this what you want (quote `I'm hoping to join the two outputs into one table`)?

Comment: The last example achieves the result in one step. I need to produce t1 and t2 separately and then combine them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will give you the expected result. In the second pipe chain which creates t2 I added `ungroup %>% group_by(Species)`. This was necessary in order to have the ID column available when calling `inner_join`.

```
library(dplyr)

t1 <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do(model = lm(formula = Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data = .)) 

t2 <- t1 %>% ungroup %>% group_by(Species) %>%
  do(summ = .$model %>% summary) 

inner_join(t1, t2)

# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
# Groups: <by row>
# 
#      Species   model                       summ
# 1     setosa <S3:lm> <S3:summaryDefault, table>
# 2 versicolor <S3:lm> <S3:summaryDefault, table>
# 3  virginica <S3:lm> <S3:summaryDefault, table>
```

Although this works, it is a kind of ugly workaround. The general problem seems to be that `do()` calls result in a data frame where the original grouping information is replaced with `<by row>`.

```
t1
# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
# Groups: <by row>
#   
#      Species   model
# 1     setosa <S3:lm>
# 2 versicolor <S3:lm>
# 3  virginica <S3:lm>
```

I don't know if this is a bug or not. Based on dplyr's behavior when using `mutate` or `summarize` I would expect that the original grouping information is either preserved or omitted. So instead of `<by row>` the data frame above should show `Species` or no grouping information at all. Perhaps someone can comment on this.

Comment: That does what I need for now - great.  Hopefully the process will smooth out in the future - this principle of tables of models and extracted bits of models is really appealing for managing large numbers